# File already used by another process in a infinity loop

Tags: c#, loops, file

Hi I'm trying to create a code generator that automatically saves the code in a file but when I do it in an infinite loop it doesn't work I've already tried with lock(obj) but it doesn't work.

I have the error "This file is already being used by another process" in an infinite loop

```
class Generator
    {

        public static int maxDigit;
        public static int codeNumber;

        public static void start()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < codeNumber; i++)
            {
                 Generate(16, maxDigit);
            }
        }

        public static void Generate(int length, int maxDigit)
        {
            var chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
            var stringChars = new char[length];
            var random = new Random();
            int counDigit = 0;
            int i = 0;
            while (i < stringChars.Length)
            {
                char c = chars[random.Next(chars.Length)];
                if ("0123456789".Contains(c) && counDigit < maxDigit)
                {
                    counDigit++;
                    stringChars[i] = c;
                    i++;
                }
                else if (!("0123456789".Contains(c)))
                {
                    stringChars[i] = c;
                    i++;
                }

            }

            var finalString = new String(stringChars);
            string filePath = @"Codes.txt";
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(filePath, true))
            {
                sw.WriteLine(finalString);
            }
        }


    }
```

Comment: Elaborate on "doesn't work." Are you getting an exception? Compiler error? Maybe try posting your real code?

Comment: I have the error "This file is already being used by another process"

Comment: Don't open the file in start() and append only in Generate!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are opening the file on the `start()` then you are trying to open it again on the `Generate` method.

Try this:

```
public static void start()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < codeNumber; i++)
    {
        //using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText("Codes.txt"))
        {
            Generate(16, maxDigit);
        }
    }
}
```

then call it using:

```
Generator.maxDigit = 9;
Generator.codeNumber = 4;
Generator.start();
```

then it generates `Codes.txt`

```
e0uhHvWadGpsHooy
njxQZ6NxN0fiEOYE
QTlZfyTGfHOfWAFJ
d2OXXzhJ1R39Z32d
```

Comment: What values you did on maxDigit and codeNumber? I tried with Generator.maxDigit = 9; and             Generator.codeNumber = 4; and it worked here

Comment: Check if you are not opening this file on other places.

Comment: I try with maxDigit = 2 and numberCode = 1000. With a small number of generated code it works but not with a large number

Comment: I tried here with maxDigit = 2 and numberCode = 1000 and it generated a file with 1004 codes. No error.

Comment: Try to Build / Clean, your App.

Comment: I created a new project and it worked but now the same code is generated several times. Do I need to create a new topic or can we continue to discuss it here?

Comment: Try to move your `var random = new Random();` to outside the `Generate` method

Comment: If this solved your initial problem, then you can mark this as answer, and post new question with new problem.

Comment: The new problem was also fixed by removing the random variable from generate thank you!